# Assigning array values while running a loop to a variable dynamically

Tags: linux, shell-script, cygwin, bash-array

The values present in indexArray are: 1  4  3  2

Below is the code snippet(This is not the complete code):

```
while read -r line;do
position=${indexArray[$counter]} # No value is assigned to "position" variable
counter=$((counter+1))
done < file.txt
```

But no value is getting assigned to position shell variable. Is there any syntax that I am missing?

Note:

I do not want to hardcode the index like below:

```
position=${indexArray[1]} # This is working as expected
```

Comment: Can you show us where and how `counter` is first assigned (i.e. the value _before_ your loop)?

Comment: Also, does it work in _no_ iteration of you loop, or only _e.g._ the first?

Comment: counter=1
while read -r line;do
position=${indexArray[$counter]} # No value is assigned to "position" variable
counter=$((counter+1))
done < file.txt

Comment: It is working as expected only if I am hardcoding the value. In none of the iterations it is working. When I am trying to display the value using below command:

echo "Value of counter is:$({indexArray[$counter]})"

Actual o/p:-  Value of counter is:
Expected o/p:- Value of counter is:1

Comment: What happens if you directly issue an `echo "Value of position is $position"`. In your statement `echo "Value of counter is:$({indexArray[$counter]})"` there is definitely a syntax error, it should read `echo "Value of counter is: ${indexArray[$counter]}"` without the additional round braces `( ... )`.

Comment: It is working now, it seems that there was some logical issue while displaying the value at the array index.